# twig get object with "-" in name

Tags: php, twig

An API return object like this

```
[attr] => stdClass Object
   (
       [id] => 555
       [ttl] => 360
       [aa-type] => NS
       [prio] => 9
   )
```

In my twig template, in FOR, how i can get aa-type ?

```
{{ value.attr.id }} -> ok
{{ value.attr.aa-type }} -> Nok because "-"
```

Comment: Try `{{ attribute(value.attr, 'aa-type') }}`

Comment: @ChrisHass It's work, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access attributes on an object with special characters you can use the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html) function

`{{ attribute(value.attr, 'aa-type') }}`